# Use Gson to retrieve List<Object> from Shared Preferences

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use Gson with shared preferences
firstly, I used this method for convert list of objects to Json and save it in shared preferences and works fine

```
public Builder add(String key, List value) {
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          editor.putString(key, gson.toJson(value));
          return this;
        }
```

Secondly, I used this method to retrieve the list

```
public <T> List<T> get(String key, Class<T> classType) {
      if (preferences.contains(key)) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<classType>>() {
        }.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(get(key, ""), type);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

I want this method to retrieve list for example when I do List it say Unknown class.

How can accomplish this?

Comment: `Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, classType);`

Comment: And reuse your Gson instance. Better yet, reuse the TypeAdapter for your type.

Comment: a little fix to Eric Cochran 's post, Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, classType).getType();

Comment: should this _gson.fromJson(get(key, ""), type)_ be  _gson.fromJson(preferences.get(key, "")_?

Comment: Thanks EricCochran & jiashie it worked for me
notice: getParameterized available from Gson 2.8.0

Answer (score -1):

save list like this

```
public static void saveData(Context context, ArrayList<YOUR MODEL> model) {

        String s = new Gson().toJson(model);
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(*your preference name*, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putString(*key*, s).apply();

    }
```

get list like this

```
public static ArrayList<YOUR MODEL> getData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(*your preference name*, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s = preferences.getString(*key*, "");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YOUR MODEL>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<YOUR MODEL> list = gson.fromJson(s, type);
    return list;
}
```

hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Your code is right but I'm trying to make a general purpose method so I can put any List<Objects> and retrieve List of any type, If you noticed I used 
public <T> List<T> get()